# Receive user defaults which we stored when user logged in (swift3...)

Tags: ios, swift

1) After logging I retrieve values from a database( OK )

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Receive user defaults which we stored when user logged in

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let firstname = defaults.string(forKey: "usernameValue")
    let lastname = defaults.string(forKey: "nameValue")
    let connect_email = defaults.string(forKey: "emailValue")
    let event_mois = defaults.array(forKey: "event_mois")
    }
```

2) After `viewDidLoad()` I make an array to feed a display (OK)

```
var sections = [
    Section(genre: " Event du mois",
            movies: ["The Incredibles", "The Incredibles"],
            expanded: false),
    Section(genre: " Top Event",
            movies: ["Guardians of the Galaxy", "The Flash", "The Avengers", "The Dark Knight"],
            expanded: false),
    Section(genre: " Event Fribourg",
            movies: ["The Walking Dead", "Insidious", "Conjuring"],
            expanded: false)
]
```

3)I would now like to take event_mois table which I retrieved from my database to put it in var sections. But I can not use this array outside of `viewDidLoad` and I can not also put var sections in viewDidload.

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Just initialise you sections array outside of `ViewDidLoad()`.

Comment: i try but the debug..
Cannot use instance member defaults within property initializers run before self is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define `sections` to be an instance property of your class, then you can access it anywhere from your class.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var sections: [Section]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Receive user defaults which we stored when user logged in

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let firstname = defaults.string(forKey: "usernameValue")
        let lastname = defaults.string(forKey: "nameValue")
        let connectEmail = defaults.string(forKey: "emailValue")
        guard let eventMois = defaults.array(forKey: "event_mois") as? [Section] else {return}

        if let sections = sections {
            sections.append(eventMois)
        } else {
            sections = eventMois
        }
    }

}
```

And use the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelcase for variable names.

Comment: thanks perfect, I don't want to take too much of your time, but just for sections = eventMois 

the debug shows this message : cannot assign value ot typa any to [section]
Do I have to proceed differently?

Comment: You need to cast `eventMois` to `[Section]`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test tonight and I accept the resolution.
Thank you very much for having taken some time and have a nice weekend.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: If you have still some more time, I have this following error message:
initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not section

       if let sections = sections

thanks

Comment: How did you declare `sections`? If you declared it optional as shown in my code, you shouldn't get that error message. If you declared it as non-optional, just leave the optional binding.

Comment: Effectively ^^
but i have Cannot use mutating member on immutable value sections is a let constant
for sections.append(eventmois)

Comment: It's not very important. I you wanna see it, I can send you the project. Otherwise have a nice weekend.

Comment: If you used the code I provided in my answer, you definitely wouldn't receive any of these errors, since I declared `sections` as a mutable variable.

Comment: I worked well last night. I have redone all the script and I recover directly on the page in Json which comes from PHP and everything works thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can not use that array in other methods since it will be out of scope.
Solution : define the array as a property, in this way you can use it anywhere in the class,  the property goes in the class outside all methods.

```
class YourClass {

    var sections : [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // your code
    }
}
```